# SQL syntax Limit 1 error

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, limit

WordPress database error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 4

for query

```
SELECT wp_wpsp_templates_fonts.name
  FROM wp_wpsp_templates_fonts
  WHERE wp_wpsp_templates_fonts.fontID = 
  LIMIT 1
```

made by

```
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/twentyten/wpsp-sales-page.php'), require_once('/plugins/wpsp/wpsp-frontend.php'), TemplatesModel->GetFontByID
```

Below is the code.

```
    function GetFontByID($fontID) {
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT ".$wpdb->prefix."wpsp_templates_fonts.name
                                    FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."wpsp_templates_fonts
                                    WHERE ".$wpdb->prefix."wpsp_templates_fonts.fontID = ".mysql_real_escape_string($fontID)."
                                    LIMIT 1");
    return $results[0]->name;    
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your variable `$fontID` doesn't appear to be set

Answer (score 0):

GetFontByID() needs a parameter passed to it.  Currently, the param appears blank.

Comment: Thank you I found what I had done. I had added a unique css style into the shared css styles. So when one of the shared templates was used it was pulling from the unique template.